# RDP to Server 2012+ visual goes fuzzy/blurry, especially inactive parts of screen (see pics)

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services

When I connect from my Windows 10 Pro (1607) to either Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows Server 2016, the text dynamically goes fuzzy. Clicking it (if it's clickable) or highlighting it makes it clear again temporarily. This affects Windows OS text, folder text including titles, and text inside of programs like Chrome, Firefox. Please see pics here...

[Image is not compressed, this is exactly how it looks on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Z7P.jpg)

My Lenovo laptop has an Intel HD Graphics 5500 adapter.

I'm using Remote Desktop Connection app (mstsc.exe) built into Windows 10 Pro.

I've tried: 
changing my DPI settings back to 100%/regular instead of my 125% 
font smoothing on/off in .rdp file
enable/disable cleartype on client AND server zoom in/out using client 
... and none of these work.

if I connect FROM a Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 client, the problem doesn't exist. If I connect TO a Windows Server 2008 R2 client or Windows 7 the problem doesn't exist.

UPDATE: using Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.2 has same effect
[RDC Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6PoQ.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the same issue with RDCMan? Trying to figure out if it's a clientside issue or server side.

Comment: Check the settings in your RDP client, specifically the "Experience" tab when making the connection.

Comment: I've tweaked all the Experience Tab options. All on, all off. 56k modem, LAN as connection speed. No difference. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Nathan, same issue in RDCMan. Screenshot added.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this on my computer, it was my Intel graphics 3D settings. 
See screen grab.  https://www.screencast.com/t/uMCvRbkll

Comment: Hello and welcome to ServerFault!
To make your answer better, you should indicate how to access the settings and describe a bit more: your screenshot might disappear some day.